# Why are gray pixels appearing on the edges of a black s:Line?

Tags: flex4, flex-spark

This is the Line i'm using:

```
<s:Line x="25" y="22" width="42">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="2" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

The result is a black line with width 44 and two gray pixels on each end of the line (the top pixels of the two vertical are gray).
How can i make the line 42 pixels in width and without gray pixels?
The current solution i've found is to use two lines one over the other like the one above with **weight="1"** but i hope there is a better one :]

Thanks in advance,

Blaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine just told me the answer. He doesn't have an account here so i thought it would be helpful to post his answer here.

```
<s:stroke>
    <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="2" caps="square"/>
</s:stroke>
```

That caps property is **round** by default.

P.S. To the moderators: please remove the whole question if you think it has no value. It's not an attempt to get points by my own answers :]